# How to set a "max wait time" for each response and go to next step if no response was giving

Tags: ruby, callback, ruby-on-rails-5

In my application I'm doing few different calls to some third-party APIs.

How am I able to set a "max wait time" for response so after for instance 200 milliseconds, if no response was giving by the service I can go to the next service API, down in the "ladder".

One of the methods that can be use in the `sleep`, like: `sleep(0.2)`, but sleep just waits 0.2 sec before executing the call instead of let the call happen and if no response, move on.

Any tips or help is very much appreciated and thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You should use Net::HTTP open_timeout and read_timeout